# Unable to get image of the barcode from ZxingScannerView after scanning

Tags: android, arrays, zxing, android-bitmap

This is my app/build.gradle file

```
dependencies{
........
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
}
```

In my MainActivity i have implemented the interface ZxingScannerView.ResultHandler

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler {
.....
.....
@Override
public void handleResult(Result result) {
    String EncodedData = result.getText;
    String BarCodeFormat = result.getBarcodeFormat().toString();
    Byte[] byteArray = result.getRawBytes();
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

}
}
```

The BarCodeFormat and EncodedData are Shown correctly.
The problem is that the bitmap is always null, so the ImageView is set to a null bitmap and nothing is shown, Where did I go wrong?

Comment: have u checked, what is null the bitmap or byteArray?

Comment: @AkashDubey byteArray is not null, the bitmap is null

Answer (score -1):

check your lib version if it is v3.0.3 or more then try this

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
integrator.initiateScan();



@override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode, data);
result.getBitmap()
}
```

Comment: even that method returned null, it didn't go into catch but returned null

Comment: where should I set this? I can't find it.